# How to update table in real time with ajax and JSP

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, ajax, jsp

I am new to programming and I have the following question.

I want to update a table through Ajax without having to press any button.

For example, if someone else enters a record in the database, I can see the records that are entered in real time in my JSP table.

I leave my code.

**In this part I show the data that is being entered, by a method that I have in the Employee class**

```
<table class="table" id="tblEmpleados">
<thead class="thead-dark" style="text-align: center">
  <tr>
    <th>Nombres</th>
    <th>Apellidos</th>
    <th>Direccion</th>
    <th>Telefono</th>
    <th>Fecha Nacimiento</th>
    <th>Correo</th>
    <th>Usuario</th>
    <th>Puesto</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="tbl_empleados">
    <%
    Empleado empleado = new Empleado();
    DefaultTableModel tabla = new  DefaultTableModel();
    tabla = empleado.leerEmpleado();
    for ( int t=0; t<tabla.getRowCount();t++){
        out.println("<tr data-id="+ tabla.getValueAt(t, 0) +">");
        out.println("<td style='text-align: center'>"+tabla.getValueAt(t,1)+"</td>");
        out.println("<td style='text-align: center'>"+tabla.getValueAt(t,2)+"</td>");
        out.println("<td style='text-align: center'>"+tabla.getValueAt(t,3)+"</td>");
        out.println("<td style='text-align: center'>"+tabla.getValueAt(t,4)+"</td>");
        out.println("<td style='text-align: center'>"+tabla.getValueAt(t,5)+"</td>");
        out.println("<td style='text-align: center'>"+tabla.getValueAt(t,6)+"</td>");
        out.println("<td style='text-align: center'>"+tabla.getValueAt(t,7)+"</td>");
        out.println("<td style='text-align: center'>"+tabla.getValueAt(t,8)+"</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");
    }
    %>
</tbody>
```

**This is the method I call in the JSP**

```
public DefaultTableModel leerEmpleado (){

DefaultTableModel tabla = new  DefaultTableModel();
  try{
      cn = new Conexion();
      cn.abrir_conexion();
      String query="SELECT E.id_empleado AS id,E.nombres,E.apellidos,E.direccion,E.telefono,E.fecha_nacimiento,E.correo,U.usuario,P.puesto from empleado E inner join usuario U on E.id_usuario=U.id_usuario inner join puesto P on E.id_puesto=P.id_puesto;";
      ResultSet consulta = cn.conexionBD.createStatement().executeQuery(query);
      String encabezado [] = {"id","Nombre","Apellido","Direccion","Telefono","Fecha Nacimiento","Correo","Usuario","Puesto"};
      tabla.setColumnIdentifiers(encabezado);
      String datos [] = new String [9];
      while (consulta.next()){
      datos[0] = consulta.getString("id");
      datos[1] = consulta.getString("nombres");
      datos[2] = consulta.getString("apellidos");
      datos[3] = consulta.getString("direccion");
      datos[4] = consulta.getString("telefono");
      datos[5] = consulta.getString("fecha_nacimiento");
      datos[6] = consulta.getString("correo");
      datos[7] = consulta.getString("usuario");
      datos[8] = consulta.getString("puesto");
      tabla.addRow(datos);
      }
      cn.cerrar_conexion();
  }catch(SQLException ex){
      System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
  }
  
  return tabla;
```

}

**and this is my Servlet that performs the operations of entering, editing and deleting**

```
  Empleado empleado;
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet sr_empleado</title>");            
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
           empleado = new Empleado(Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("drop_usuario")),Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("drop_puesto")),Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("txt_id")),request.getParameter("txt_nombres"),request.getParameter("txt_apellidos"),request.getParameter("txt_direccion"),request.getParameter("txt_telefono"),request.getParameter("txt_fn"),request.getParameter("txt_correo"));
        // Boton agregar 
        if ("agregar".equals(request.getParameter("btn_agregar"))){
         if (empleado.agregar()>0){
         response.sendRedirect("CrudEmpleado.jsp");
         
         }else{
         out.println("<h1> xxxxxxx No se Ingreso xxxxxxxxxxxx </h1>");
         out.println("<a href='CrudEmpleado.jsp'>Regresar...</a>");
         }
         }
        
        // Boton modificar 
        if ("modificar".equals(request.getParameter("btn_modificar"))){
         if (empleado.modificar()>0){
         response.sendRedirect("CrudEmpleado.jsp");
         
         }else{
         out.println("<h1> xxxxxxx No se Modifico xxxxxxxxxxxx </h1>");
         out.println("<a href='CrudEmpleado.jsp'>Regresar...</a>");
         }
         }
        
        // Boton eliminar 
        if ("eliminar".equals(request.getParameter("btn_eliminar"))){
         if (empleado.eliminar()>0){
         response.sendRedirect("CrudEmpleado.jsp");
         
         }else{
         out.println("<h1> xxxxxxx No se Elimino xxxxxxxxxxxx </h1>");
         out.println("<a href='CrudEmpleado.jsp'>Regresar...</a>");
         }
         }
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is ajax code ? Did you tried anything to achieve above ?